# Can I Share My Mobile Broadband Internet Through Ad Hoc Connection?

Tags: windows-7, internet, ad-hoc-network, mobile-broadband

I have a USB Mobile Broadband for my Internet. it doesn't support WiFi function. Is it possible to share my internet connection to another computer through ad hoc? Assuming both computers are running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your internet is provided by a USB device, that would be no different that internet being provided by wireless or Ethernet, as long as the USB device does not have any restrictive programming that comes with it, and your computer has wireless you should be able to set up ad hoc, I would try this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-computer-to-computer-adhoc-network#1TC=windows-7